# Can a process have more than one stdout and stdin?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, posix

When writing a program (Unix-style), can it address and manage more than one stdout and stdin channels?

Comment: I am curious what you imagine it would mean for a process to have more than one stdout. Where would the output of `printf` go, for instance?

Comment: I would have imagined some way to select the particular channel onto which to print to via an overloaded method. I was looking at the websocketd daemon and wondered can one implement the actor as a long running process which just gets new destination streams to write to. I imagine working with sockets or other light weight communication streams would be next best option but I wanted the simplicity of the srd stdout.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like what you're looking for `fopen()` and `fprintf()`, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If what you are in fact asking is "can a process be given more than one output or more than one input from its parent process", then the answer is "yes"; any number of file-descriptors can be carried over an `exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; there is (at most) one standard input and one standard output at any given time.  Ultimately, since the question specifically mentions Unix, standard input is file descriptor 0 and standard output is file descriptor 1, and there is only one file descriptor with a given number.

Answer (score 2):

By definition there is only 1 stdin and 1 stdout.

However, you may want to have a look at named pipes. With named pipes you could do something like:

```
mkfifo pipe1
mkfifo pipe2
cat a.a > pipe1
cat b.b > pipe2
yourapp pipe1 pipe2
```